# How to handle Application “Crash” when Run Test Suite.(Android)

Tags: automation, appium, appium-android, katalon-studio, test-suite

on Running Test Suite(with 20-30 test cases) on Emulator time application crashed after run 6-7 test cases,its working when we execute on physical device.but we have to work with emulator,we are using Android Emulator and Genymotion.

Answer (score 1):

**@lav Sharma** , could You please expand a bit more here please:

- what .apk version do You use for execution?  Debug or non debug?
- second point, could You please play a bit with the flag [setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/8162#issuecomment-300181003) 
  and ask devs to turn it ON   `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);`

or OFF  `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(false);`

in the onCreate method of the app;

- for the investigation of the issue - please collect application logs (during tests execution)  and post the exception here .   To dump the logs - please use the method below:

  ```
  List<LogEntry> logs = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").getAll();
  ```

  `public static void dumpLogs(AppiumDriver driver, String testName)
   {
      String logPath = "C:\\automation_capture\\";
      log.info("{}: Saving device log...", driver.getSessionId());
      List<LogEntry> logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").filter(Level.ALL);
      File logFile = new File(String.format("%s_%s.txt",logPath,testName));
      PrintWriter log_file_writer = new PrintWriter(logFile);
      log_file_writer.println(logEntries );
      log_file_writer.flush();
      log.info("{}: Saving device log - Done.",driver.getSessionId());
      }
  }`

Hope this helps. 
best regards,
Eugene